# Private or default visibility for "file-private" members?

Tags: java, packages, access-modifiers

I have a class like this

```
public final class Outer {
    static final class Inner {
        /* Used in the package. */
        void f() {...}

        /* Used in Outer. */
        WHATEVER void g() {...}

        /* Used in Inner only. */
        private void h() {...}
    }
}
```

In Java, every member defined in the same file can access every other member (*), so `g` may be `private`. The alternative is the default visibility.

The obvious advantage of `private` is that it's the minimum possible visibility. Using it you can be sure that there are no users of `g` outside of the file.

There are disadvantages, too:

As such an access is allowed by Java but not by the JVM, a bridge method gets created, which then appears in stacktraces and in the debugger. They also slow down the program, but this is negligible as they usually get inlined anyway.

What troubles me more is that with `g` being `private`, I can't see if it's meant to be used outside of `Inner` or if it's "really-private" (like `h`).

My questions are

- what's the best practice?
- is there an annotation for such a case (and does it get recognized by a tool)?
- how do other languages deal with it?

---

(*) As stated in Timothy Truckle's answer, this is only true assuming that you don't pack additional non-public classes in the same file (which hardly anybody does since nested classes were introduced in Java 1.1).

Comment: Have you made a proof test?

Comment: @Laiv Test of what? I've verified Timothy's claim and I'm rather sure about my claims.

Comment: It's not the next sentence the source of the doubts? `I can't say if it's meant to be used outside of Inner or if it's "really-private" (like h).`

Comment: @Laiv I meant "I can't see..."; it's about me not being able to recognize things not meant to be used outside of `Inner` *at the first glance* even in my own code. I find it disturbing and it slows me down.

Comment: Oh. Ok I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the rcords:

> In Java, every member defined in the same file can access every other member,

This statement is wrong as it stands there.

It is true (and you most likely meant that) only for *inner classes*.

But you can define several classes within the same file (where only one can be `public`, the others must be *package private*

And this could be the solution for your problem: move the class `Inner` out of the class `Outer` within the same file:

```
public final class Outer {
  public void somMethod(){
    new Inner().f(); // OK
    new Inner().h(); // compile error
  }
}
static final class Inner {
    /* Used in the package. */
    void f() {...}

    /* Used in Outer. */
    void g() {...}

    /* Used in Inner only. */
    private void h() {...}
}
```

But Java has no possibility to restrict access to "only in same file".

Answer (score 2):

In Java outer classes have full access to all elements of the Inner Classes as well as all inner classes have full access to the element of the outer classes.

The access modifiers becomes important when you derive from an inner class

```
public class Outer {

    static class A {
        void f() {}

        public void g() {}

        private void h() {}

    }

    static  class B extends A {

        public void g() {
            f(); // OK 
            h(); // Compiler error 
        }
    }
}
```

Or when you try to access the elements of the Inner class from outside of `Outer`

```
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String ... args) {
       new Outer.A().f(); // OK if in the same package  
       new Outer.A().g(); // OK
       new Outer.A().h(); // Compiler error.
   }
}
```

If you want to ensure that your outer class can only access "public" elements / methods of your inner class define an interface.

```
public class Outer {
    private interface MySuperInterface {
         void g();
    }

    static class A implements MySuperInterface {
        public void g();

    }

    void foo() {
        MySuperInterface x = new A();
        x.g();
    }

}
```

These architecture constraints can be enforced by tools / frameworks like the [Java Modelling Language (JML)](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML//index.shtml) or [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net)